# RNAseq and TTseq results

Tags: rna-seq

I'm working with two sets of data. One of two sets of data, one contains the results of a RNAseq analysis and the other contains the result of TTseq analysis. I want to check which genes overlap in both data sets to check if the are affected at stabilization level or at a transcriptional level. If anyone knows how the coding pipeline it would help me. I work on linux.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.